# Trying to scrape site for all the shoes on the page, but keeps returning None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

im trying to scrape this site for all the shoes on the page, but it keeps returning None, this is the link https://www.goat.com/sneakers, 
and this is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url = 'https://www.goat.com/sneakers'
headers= {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 
Safari/537.36',
}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = bs(page, "html.parser")
containers = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'cell'})
for container in containers:
    print(container)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please attempt to solve this problem and show us what have you done.

Comment: Content is loaded from a json request, Parse it directly.

Comment: sorry im fairly new to programming, how would i parse it directly?

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by @PedroLobito, the web page doesn't respond directly with the data, it is loaded after the initial request using JavaScript. That is why you're not seeing anything: the original HTML doesn't have the sneaker data. The data is retrieved from an endpoint that returns JSON. It's easier to request that directly.

Using the developer tools built in the the web browser we can see a POST request is made to:

```
https://2fwotdvm2o-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/product_variants_v2/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.25.1&x-algolia-application-id=2FWOTDVM2O&x-algolia-api-key=ac96de6fef0e02bb95d433d8d5c7038a
```

and the payload is

```
{"params":"distinct=true&facetFilters=()&facets=%5B%22size%22%5D&hitsPerPage=20&numericFilters=%5B%5D&page=0&query="}
```

We can request this directly with requests and use the `json()` method of the response object to actually use the data, for example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = 'https://2fwotdvm2o-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/product_variants_v2/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.25.1&x-algolia-application-id=2FWOTDVM2O&x-algolia-api-key=ac96de6fef0e02bb95d433d8d5c7038a'
data = {"params":"distinct=true&facetFilters=()&facets=%5B%22size%22%5D&hitsPerPage=20&numericFilters=%5B%5D&page=0&query="}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
print(r.json()['hits'][0])
```

which gives us

```
{'product_template_id': 116662, 'shoe_condition': 'used', 'box_condition': 'badly_damaged', 'lowest_price_cents': 18500, 'instant_ship_lowest_price_cents': None, 'brand_name': 'adidas', 'category': ['lifestyle'], 'color': 'White', 'designer': 'Kanye West', 'details': 'Cream White/Cream White/Core White', 'gender': ['men'], 'grid_picture_url': 'https://image.goat.com/375/attachm...
```

Comment: wow, I wish you could understand how much that helped me, also how would i know if a page is loading the data from html or json, and how would i find the right endpoint?

Comment: Check your browser's documentation for information on "developer tools", specifically the "network inspector" tab that is usually available. That + the raw HTML is usually enough to tell.

Comment: what do u mean by the documentation? like look it up? also are u talking about in the chrome dev tools, under network, i check the responses for all the requests to see which data is the one im looking for?

Comment: Like [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). And yes, Chrome Dev tools > Network is one example. If you have any questions after researching, please create a separate specific question.